# Android, performance degrading if multiple activities

Tags: android, performance, opengl-es, android-activity

I have an OpenGL based app, all is working fine so far. The app consists out ouf 2 activities, the main activity containing the OpenGL view and an additional activity that contains a movie player for some cut-scenes.

On some low-end devices (e.g. LG P690, Android 2.3.4) performance degrades significantly after the movie-activity ran. After that the main activity runs so slow that it only reaches about 30 fps instead of 50 fps.

You can "fix" it to become fast again, if you leave the app by pushing the home-button and restart it. Then all is fine again - until that movie-view-activity is shown again...

I did some tests and this effect is also happening regardless of what activity #2 actually does, even if it is just a splash-screen or whatever. If I never invoke a second activity then the performance is always high.

Note: the OpenGL activity is *not* instanciated multiple times, which would probably lead to a similar effect.

Has somebody experienced the same or a similar issue and knows a remedy?

Comment: Maybe whatever you are using to render the movie uses opengl-es? I must admit I do everything in one activity, but that is probably not always a good idea :P

Comment: The effect happens regardless of what activity #2 actually does (even if it does nothing at all), so it is definitely not related to any movie rendering mechanics.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunaly i lack of reputation to just leave a comment.

I could imagine that a new instance of your opengl activity is started when you return from your 2nd.

You might wanna put a specific intent to avoid that.

I would try FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP for example.

Give the developers Page on intents a look: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

All Flag`s are listed there with description.

Hope that lead´s to a solution for you!

Comment: This was a valid idea but unfortunately that's not the case here, the OpenGL activity is not instanciated multiple times. Thanks for your efforts nevertheless. I'll edit may question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the same problem on two of my devices:

- acer liquid metal (android 2.3) drops from 50 to 45 fps in my ap
- 'cube' 10.1" tablet (android 4.0) - drops from 60 to 30 fps in my app

However I am using the canvas approach with the SurfaceView attached directly as a child to my Activity.

I have investigated, and using a `dialog` instead of an activity works. Another thing that seems to work is changing the Manifest entry for your activity to have the attribute as follows:

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"`

Please note: using either of these techniques solves the problem, HOWEVER the lifecycle events for your calling activity WILL NOT operate as before. I.e. onPause will not be called etc. You will need to move custom code from those methods into your dialog opening code.

This was a real pain to discover and debug. I wish this issue didnt exist.